Bridging two edge loops creates weird effect in smooth shading
I created a bezier curve and converted it into a mesh so I can bridge it's edge loop with the edge loop of another object. Before I bridges the loops I joined both objects. I deleted any faces between the edges to be connected. I made sure that both loops had the same amount of edges. I haven't applied any modifiers to either of the objects, just shade smooth. it looks normal without shade smooth. I'm a beginner so if you need any further information let me know.



